# Error import image PIL For a phyton tkinter program. How to display images

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, mysql-python

When I write this code it work

```
    self.logo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\images\logo.png")
```

but I want to write it like this

```
    self.logo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/logo.png")
```

I have already done pip install pillow

Comment: Maybe look into how _relative path_ works

Comment: I have tried everything its not working

Comment: Okay so what have you tried?